# Are automorphism groups of polarized varieties of finite type

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, stacks, automorphism-groups, algebraic-stacks

It is "well-known" that the stack of polarized varieties is an algebraic stack with quasi-compact and separated diagonal.

In particular, if $(X,L)$ and $(Y,M)$ are polarized schemes over a scheme $S$, the Isom-scheme $$Isom((X,L),(Y,M))$$ is separated and quasi-compact over $S$.

I had the feeling that these Isom-schemes should be of finite type and affine over $S$ and surely this is well-known. In other words,

Is the diagonal  of the stack of polarized varieties of finite type?

Is it affine?

I did not find an answer in the stacks project. I'm currently looking at work of Rydh and others, but haven't gotten lucky yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Breaking with my habit of writing everything in comments, this is Section 2.1 of my article with de Jong.

MR2745688 (2012e:14073) Reviewed 
Starr, Jason(1-SUNYS); de Jong, Johan(1-CLMB) 
Almost proper GIT-stacks and discriminant avoidance. (English summary) 
 
Doc. Math. 15 (2010), 957–972. 
14J10 (14L15) 
http://www.math.uiuc.edu/documenta/vol-15/29.pdf

Comment: Section 2.1 gives a proof for why the Isom-scheme is affine. Whether the Isom-scheme is of finite type over the base is not discussed, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I suppose that we do not explicitly say that it is finite type over the base, but we factor the morphism as (first) a closed immersion (automatically finite type) followed by an explicit finite type affine morphism.  The $\mathcal{O}_U$-modules $f_*\mathcal{N}$ and $g_*\mathcal{L}$ are locally free sheaves of finite ranks $r$ and $s$.  Thus $\text{Isom}_U(f_*\mathcal{N},g_*\mathcal{L})$ is empty if $r\neq s$, and it is (Zariski locally) $\text{GL}_{r,U}$ if $r$ equal $s$.

Comment: Yes, I realized this shortly after writing my comment. :) I guess one could also say that you are showing the Isom-schemes map finitely to the automorphism group of some projective bundle over $U$ associated to some vector bundle on U, right?

Comment: Basically that is what we were saying.  Also Section 2.1 is basically a summary of what is in other references (which we list there).  We spelled things out a bit more than other authors.  However, as you identified, we also left many things unsaid.

Comment: Also, slightly related to $\text{Isom}$ begin finitely generated is Lemma 4.7 in another of my papers with de Jong, "Every Rationally Connected Variety ...".

Comment: Thanks again! I look forward to reading these articles over the summer.